# Hide IE warnings from console in Angular 6

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, sass, angular-cli, angular6

I am constantly getting these warnings when serving my angular app:

[image]
e.g.:

```
./src/app/core/containers/navbar/navbar.component.sass
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) autoprefixer: ...src\app\core\containers\navbar\navbar.component.sass:11:4: grid-auto-columns is not supported by IE
```

Unfortunately, I am not interested in IE support. **Is it possible to disable this type of warnings?**

Comment: **Unfortunately!?!?** I think you mean **Fortunately**! Supporting IE is a plague on all front end developers!

Comment: Yeah, you are 100% right :D But do you have a solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can disable warnings for single lines in your CSS file by prepending the line with:

```
/* autoprefixer: off */
```

For example, IE does not support the CSS setting `grid-auto-rows`. To disable the warning, apply it like this:

```
.some-div {
    display: grid;
    /* autoprefixer: off */
    grid-auto-rows: auto auto;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5964

Comment: Thank you so much!